# Invalid parameter: token account is not defined in the query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I have two query builders defined.

First: Returns all accounts of an user.

Seconds: Returns all user transactions by account.

First:

```
public function getAccountsList($user)
{
    return $this->getAccountRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->where('a.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Second:

```
 public function  getTransactionsList($user)
{
    $accounts = $this->getAccountsList($user);

    $query = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t')
        ->where('t.account IN (:accounts)')
        ->setParameter('account', $accounts)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $query;
}
```

First works perfect but second throws an error:

> Invalid parameter: token account is not defined in the query

How to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`token account is not defined in the query`

That mean `->setParameter('account', ...)` is anywhere is the query

in your `->where` you have set the token `:accounts` with the `S` and the end, typo error

Correct answer is

```
public function  getTransactionsList($user) {
    $accounts = $this->getAccountsList($user);

    $query = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t')
        ->where('t.account IN (:accounts)')
        ->setParameter('accounts', $accounts)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! @DylanDelobel

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in account parameters

```
 public function  getTransactionsList($user)
{
    $accounts = $this->getAccountsList($user);

    $query = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t')
        ->where('t.account IN (:accounts)')
        ->setParameter('account', $accounts)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $query;
}
```

As you can see...

```
->where('t.account IN (:accounts)')

->setParameter('account', $accounts)
```

One is accounts and the other is account. Should be:

```
 public function  getTransactionsList($user)
{
    $accounts = $this->getAccountsList($user);

    $query = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t')
        ->where('t.account IN (:accounts)')
        ->setParameter('accounts', $accounts)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $query;
}
```